# Unable to create lock file when starting mongod via upstart

Tags: permissions, services, lock, mongodb

I'm trying to set up my mongodb upstart script to work as an arbiter, but I'm having permission problems when trying to create the lock file in the data directory:

```
Tue Apr  1 17:11:01 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/tmp/arb", journal: "true", logappe
nd: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb-arbiter.log", port: 27017, replSet: "rs1" }
Tue Apr  1 17:11:01 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /tmp/arb/mongod.l
ock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

There definitely is no lock file present and there definitely is no other `mongod` process running (`ps -A | grep mongod` will return nothing).

Also when I try to start the `mongod` process

```
mongod --fork --port 27017 --dbpath /data/arb --replSet rs1 --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
```

this will also throw the same error when not `sudo`ed.

How can I setup the right permissions for the upstart script to write data in `/data/arb` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the permissions on that folder (and everything under it) such that the `mongodb` user can write to it.  The reason it is working with `sudo` is because the `root` user has those permissions regardless of the owner/group.  In fact, that may be the root cause here - when you run the `mongod` process with sudo it will create the files with `root:root` ownership which the normal mongodb user cannot access.

The `user:group` for MongoDB on Ubuntu is usually `mongodb:mongodb`, hence just do the following:

```
cd /tmp/arb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb .
```

Since you are running an arbiter here I would also recommend the following options in your config file (note: not for use on a regular data bearing node - arbiter only):

- [nojournal](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#nojournal)=true
- [noprealloc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#noprealloc) = true
- [oplogsize](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#oplogSize) = 1
- [smallfiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#smallfiles)=true

These settings will minimize the footprint of the arbiter on the host.